# How to dynamically create Javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to dynamically merge/insert objects to refactor a bunch of API request object types and I can't seem to find a clear answer.

```
let isThingTrue = true;

let dynamicObjectItem1 = {"foo": "bar"};

let dynamicObject = {
"item1": "stuff here",
"item2": "stuff here",
isThingTrue ? dynamicObject : <add nothing>
"item3": "stuff here
};
```

If isThingTrue is true, then object looks like:

```
{
"item1": "stuff here",
"item2": "stuff here",
"foo": "bar",
"item3": "stuff here
}
```

If isThingTrue is false, then object looks like:

```
{
"item1": "stuff here",
"item2": "stuff here",
"item3": "stuff here
}
```

Is this possible? Adding a value like this doesn't work.

```
let dynamicObjectItem1 = {"foo": "bar"};

let dynamicObjectStart = {
"item1": "stuff here",
"item2": "stuff here",
dynamicObjectItem1,
"item3": "stuff here"
};
```

Which produces:

```
{
"item1": "stuff here",
"item2": "stuff here",
"dynamicObjectItem1": {
   "foo": "bar"
   }
"item3": "stuff here"
};
```

Is there a clean way to make this work without a bunch of Object.assigns?

Comment: Just assign `undefined` to `foo` if you don't want the value `"bar"`, that should be as good as not having the property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const makeObj = isThingTrue => {
  let dynamicObjectItem1 = {
    "foo": "bar"
  };
  return {
    "item1": "stuff here",
    "item2": "stuff here",
    ...isThingTrue && dynamicObjectItem1,
      "item3": "stuff here"
  };
}
console.log(makeObj(true));
console.log(makeObj(false));
```